# Inserting elements into a LinkedList in ascending order

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to find an efficient way to insert `Integer` elements into a `java.util.LinkedList` list while always maintaining ascending order. For example:

```
5 -> []        => [5]
1 -> [5]       => [1, 5]
3 -> [1, 5]    => [1, 3, 5]
0 -> [1, 3, 5] => [0, 1, 3, 5]
```

This is purely theoretical problem to understand the impact of list traversal in linked data structure, see [this presentation](http://youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo). I'm not interested in batch inserting `Integer` elements or sorting the `LinkedList` at the end.

I can use the `ListIterator` however it requires two method calls. I have to perform `set()`  followed by `add()` like:

```
var numbers = new Integer[] { 5, 1, 3, 0, ... };
var list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
outer:
for (Integer num : numbers) {
  var it = list.listIterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    var el = it.next();
    if (num <= el) {
      it.set(num);
      it.add(el);
      continue outer;
    }
  }
  it.add(num);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Unless there is a different implementation of linked list data structure already in the JDK and it will be more suited for this task I'm not interested in swapping out `java.util.LinkedList` for something else.

Comment: Is your real use case such that `numbers` cannot simply be sorted? I don't see how that would be less efficient than your current implementation.

Comment: @ernest_k There is no real use case, this is a theoretical problem to understand the significance of list traversal in linked data structure, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Comment: Seems clear to me that a linked list is a wrong choice to solve this problem. And from the fact that you want to stick with it, I fail to see what the outcome of your analysis is expected to be. But that could be just me.

Comment: @ernest_k Can you please explain why it's obvious that `LinkedList` is wrong choice for this problem? The video that I linked shows that this problem is not obvious, `LinkedList` has better complexity for insertion operation than `ArrayList` however `ArrayList` is practically faster for large `N`. I wonder what makes it obvious?

Comment: Well, if you didn't *have to* use a linked list, you would probably be using something like a tree set, priority queue or other sorted collection. And I wasn't contrasting your solution to using an array list, which is a different question. If your exercise is to implement something like that on top of a linked list, then I still don't understand how you'd get to *the impact of list traversal in linked data structure* without comparing it to other data structures. Again, this could just be me.

Comment: @ernest_k good point, I will consider `PriorityQueue` and `TreeSet` as other examples of linked data structure. The original question stands, can the provided code for `LinkedList` be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Add method can take two inputs.

```
void add(int index, Object element)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-linkedlist-add-method-in-java/

Do binary search, find the position, use add method....